# What are my options - TA to QR conversion

Tags: wheels, parts, axle, conversion, quick-release

I’ve just bought these wheels on gumtree and didn’t realise they were thru axle as I require quick release for my cx bike (BH RX team cross 2014 https://issuu.com/bhbikesusa/docs/bh_bikes_2014-2015_catalog/12?ff). The wheels are bontrager tubeless ready rims , with alloy sealed bearings, 12 mm alloy axle, CenterLock. They are off of a trek checkpoint (https://www.trekbikes.com/au/en_AU/bikes/road-bikes/gravel-bikes/checkpoint/checkpoint-sl/checkpoint-sl-5/p/24387/?colorCode=red)

Am I able to swap out the TA end caps for QR end caps? And what is the requirement for the rear wheel by comparison to the front. Having installed a 10 speed cassette I can’t see how an end cap will integrate.

Thanks in advance,

J[image: rear wheel hub]!

Comment: Depends on brand and model - some can be converted, others not.  Without knowing the brand and model of hub, we cannot answer the question.  I won't rely on the link as this detail can vary from country and year, whats on the hubs?

Comment: Bontrager is Trek's in house brand.  I'd recommend popping down to your local Trek dealer and asking what (if anything) can be done.

Comment: Thanks Andy P, I'll do that. Thanks for the suggestions.